# Did Facebook made any changes to the Login API in 2014?

Tags: asp.net, facebook, dotnetopenauth

Currently I am facing problems while using the **Facebook Login API** authentication in `asp.net`. My app was working and everything was fine, but recently I was testing it and suddenly it won't redirect me anymore to the **Facebook** Login Page.

Does anyone know if Facebook made any breaking changes to the **Login API**?

Comment: If you check roadmap you'll notice that there wasn't any change applied to the Login API  https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/completed-changes/

Comment: this is not the place to ask this question. that being said, did you migrate your app. i also saw some changes and i am curious to know ;)

Comment: hey @naveen what do u mean "not the place" where do u think so the place to ask then? i am facing problem so i have posted it. and this might also help people like you too right?

Comment: the best place to ask is the facebook forum. one could help if you could provide your endpoints and any error message you get in console or wherever. this is a programming QA site. if you can paste your code i could check and tell.